# Which Person(s) of the Trinity were in Jesus?

Tags: trinity, christology, incarnation

The doctrine of the Trinity teaches that God is one, and God is three (Father, Son, Holy Spirit.) From what I understand the Eternal Son came in human flesh, and we know that resultant man as Jesus of Nazareth. So would it be accurate to say God the Son was operating in a human body as "Jesus"? Were the Father and/or Spirit also in Him?

*(I am, of course, looking for answers from a Trinitarian perspective.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All three persons of the Trinity are in a perichoretic union.<sup>1</sup> Hence, the Holy Spirit is called the Spirit of the Father<sup>2</sup> and the Spirit of the Son,<sup>3</sup> yet there still exist three persons of the Trinity.<sup>4</sup>

The Son said, “I and my Father are one,”<sup>5</sup> to which the Jews picked up stones in order to stone him. He also told Phillip, “I am in the Father and the Father is in me.”<sup>6</sup> By means of the Holy Spirit, the other Comforter,<sup>7</sup> the Father and the Son would dwell in individual Christians.<sup>8</sup>

The Father is essentially and spiritually (obviously, not physically, as in the sense of a corporality) in the Son, as the Son is spiritually in the Father, and both are spiritually in the Holy Spirit, as there is a unity of essence. In such a manner, the Father is indeed in the Son, not only by a unity of will, as some assert. Thus, the apostle Paul wrote that “God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto Himself.”<sup>9</sup>

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> From the Greek word περιχώρησις
<sup>2</sup> Matt. 10:20 cp. Mark 13:11
<sup>3</sup> Gal. 4:6
<sup>4</sup> Matt. 28:19
<sup>5</sup> John 10:30
<sup>6</sup> John 14:10–11
<sup>7</sup> John 14:16
<sup>8</sup> John 14:23
<sup>9</sup> 2 Cor. 5:19

Answer (score 1):

Jesus is one Person of the Trinity.  He is never the Father or the Spirit.  That being said, Jesus did speak of the union He had with the others when He said "the Father was in Him" and such.  However, it was the Son who became a Man--not the Father or the Spirit.

> In that day you will know that I am in My Father, and you in Me, and I in you.  John 14:20 NAS

The Father and the Spirit are spirit and do not have physical bodies, so neither of them could be physically in the body of Jesus.

Comment: Last para is completely off the topic and goes without saying. Reason for downvote.

Comment: @jayyeshu Pretty harsh criteria.

Comment: Oh! is it? I thought Mods are using much harsher criteria (Albeit they should). Anyway, I shall revise my scale.

Comment: @jayyeshu I wouldn't say it's way off topic, but even if it is, a comment to that end with a revision suggestion seems to be more appropriate.  I reserve downvotes for faulty reasoning and things like that.  So, that's my practice.  Of course, you are welcome to define your own practices.  Still, if you can make a strong case for why the last paragraph does not belong, I could be persuaded.

Answer (score 1):

Clarity might come with a clear definition of what the Trinity doctrine seeks to state. It cannot explain how this mystery of the Godhead 'works', only that the Bible shows this to be the case:

Three Persons share divine nature, and have done from before time began - in eternity. The Father and the Son share the one, divine nature, with absolute unity of the Spirit in that nature.

The starting point has to be as per John 1:1-14 - "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and God was the Word." Then John goes on to explain how the eternal Word of God came into this world as flesh; adding to his divine nature human nature. The Word, who made everything that was made, could never have been made himself, otherwise that verse would have had to qualify the statement by saying the Word "made all *other* things that were made." It does not. It cannot. The Word was not made. In due time, while we were still helpless in our sin, the Word became flesh and dwelt among us. He was fully man, fully died, and was fully resurrected to go back to where he had come from, alongside God. ***This answers your question as to whether God the Son was operating in a human body as "Jesus".*** He was more than merely 'operating'. He was fully human whilst retaining his divine nature. It was his bodily resurrection that proved him to be the Son of God - Romans 1:1-4.

***You also ask, "Were the Father and/or Spirit also in Him?"*** There are many New Testament verses showing that. Consider how the Holy Spirit drove him into the wilderness immediately after his baptism. This wasn't an external suggestion that got Jesus thinking, "I need to go into the wilderness now." He was driven forcefully by the power of the Holy Spirit. Consider how Jesus rebuked Philip for asking to see the Father: "Have I been so long time with you, and yet hast thou not known me, Philip? He that hath seen me hath seen the Father... Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me... And I will pray the Father, and he shall give you another Comforter, that he may abide with you for ever; the Spirit of truth..." (John 14:9-17)

The New Testament clearly shows the inter-working of all three Persons, even while the Son was walking on the Earth as the man, Jesus. This means that ***your main question, "Which Person(s) of the Trinity were in Jesus"*** is answered by grasping that all three divine Persons work totally in harmony at all times, as the One being of God; before creation began; during the incarnation; after Jesus' resurrection and return to where he had come from.

Just bear in mind that the name "God" encompasses all three divine Persons, whilst they retain their individual roles and functions within the Godhead. The Bible speaks of Father, Son, and Holy Spirit with regard to their particular dealings (both in relation to humanity, and with each other). I hope that helps clarify this complex matter a little.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your second Question only because the first seems very complicated and technical.

**Were the Father and/or Spirit also in Him?**

**Answer**: yes the Holy Spirit was in Him, no the Father was not in him (he was in Him in a metaphorical sense though) He was in heaven.

**Scriptural Support**

> Luk_3:22  And the Holy Ghost descended in a bodily shape like a dove upon him, and a voice came from heaven, which said, Thou art my beloved Son; in thee I am well pleased.

God the Father (voice from heaven) is in heaven and The Holy Spirit descends upon Jesus. Simple and straight forward. all other arguments are just metaphors for example

> John 10:30
> I and my Father are one.

While reading the Bible go to the clearest passages before going to the metaphoric ones. For example when studying the state of the dead do not start with the parable of Lazarus and the richman (please don't that's a parable you can find clearer statements which talk on that issue)

If you anyone does not agree here is a passage for you:

> John 14:23  Jesus replied: If anyone loves me, they will obey me. Then my Father will love them, and we will come to them and live in them.

Obviously this is metaphoric because Jesus is in the Heavenly sanctuary now:

> Heb 4:14  Seeing then that we have a great high priest, that is passed into the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast our profession
>
> Heb 8:1  Now of the things which we have spoken this is the sum: We have such an high priest, who is set on the right hand of the throne of the Majesty in the heavens;
>
> Heb 8:2  A minister of the sanctuary, and of the true tabernacle, which ***the Lord pitched, and not man.***

When He finishes this ministry He will surely come again...

> Rev 22:12  And, behold, ***I come quickly***; and *my reward is with me*, to give every man according as his work shall be.